# Get protected assets in rails with curl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, curl

I want to access the following asset in my rails application:

```
/users/1/posts/1.json
```

Which would be json output of a user's post, simply a string.

However to access the asset the user must be logged in. Currently the session controller takes params[:email] and params[:password], the controller searches the User model by e-mail and then assigns a session variable to log the user in.

I've tried variations curl -d or curl--data giving the e-mail, the most promising one seems to be:

```
curl -d 'email[content]=email' -d 'password[content]=password'  /session/create
```

However output of the curl command gives:

```
SQLException: no such column: email.content:
```

How I can fashion my curl commands to access this asset?

Answer (score 1):

```
curl -d 'user[email]=email' -d 'user[password]=password' /session/create
```

Post vars for Rails forms are always `model[column]`

If you want to stay logged in, then you will have to use curl's cookie jar to keep the session ID in between requests. Just add the --cookie-jar option which takes a path to a file.

```
curl -d 'user[email]=email' -d 'user[password]=password' --cookie-jar /tmp/cookiejar /session/create
curl --cookie-jar /tmp/cookiejar /users/1/posts/1.json
```